# What is the equivalent of input function found in python for R?

Tags: r

In python, the function input is used along with an assignment to a variable. I have code where I am assigning the input of the user to the variables outcome and state, but R will not take the function. What is the equivalent of this in R and please show an example.

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
     #read file function
  dataTable  <- read.csv("outcome.csv", header = TRUE)
  choice <- state
  stateOfChoice <- dataTable[which(dataTable$state == choice),]

  if (outcome == "heart attack"){
    #subsetting,selecting column of "Lower mortality estimate [xxxSpecified  Outcomexxx ]"  & the Hospital name attach to it
    heart_attack <- outcome[which.min(outcome$Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack),]
    name <- heart_attack$state
    hospital <- heart_attack$Hospital.Name
  }
  return(hospital)

}


main <- function() {
  print("Type Heart Attack, .....")

  outcome <- input("Type your selection")

  print("Select state")

  state <- input("Type in your selection")

  best(state,outcome)
}

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R, this would be readline.

e.g.

```
> name <- readline(prompt="Enter name: ")
Enter name: Blah Blah
> paste0(name)
[1] "Blah Blah"
```